# Missing space in `ps` output near EOL

Tags: ps, xterm

Note the missing space before `foo`:

```
$ ps wafux | grep foo
[....]   21742  0.0  0.0  10688  2296 pts/2    S+   23:30   0:00              \_ grep --color=autofoo
$ echo $COLUMNS 
99
```

Compare with this:

```
$ ps wafux | grep foo
[....]   22183  0.0  0.0  10688  2276 pts/2    S+   23:40   0:00              \_ grep --color=auto foo
$ echo $COLUMNS 
100
```

In *both* cases the last `oo` in the output is on a second line. A screenshot for illustration after resizing (with username and first prompt line stripped):

[image: screenshot]

Is there some configuration issue or a known issue? My prompt doesn't contain any formatting codes after the newline:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$PS1"
$'$(exit_code=$?; [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s \\[$BOLD_FORMAT\\] \\[$ERROR_FORMAT\\] $exit_code \\[$RESET_FORMAT\\] " ")\\u@\\[$BOLD_FORMAT\\]\\[$WARNING_FORMAT\\]\\h\\[$RESET_FORMAT\\]:\\[$BOLD_FORMAT\\]\\[$INFO_FORMAT\\]\\w\\[$RESET_FORMAT\\]\\[\\033]0;\\u@\\h:${PWD}\\007\\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\n$ '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this occurs only with coloring, this looks like [this grep bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=477461).

A workaround is to use `ne` in the `GREP_COLORS` settings, e.g.: `GREP_COLORS=ne`

Comment: Yep. It's been [forwarded to the GNU mailing list](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15444), but it seems it's an XTerm (and other terminals) bug, so I'm not holding my breath.